# Google Sheets Array sum not working? where am I going wrong?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image: screenshot]

I know this is a super beginner thing, but this is my first time using google sheets and I cannot understand their built-in assistance for what I need.

I have 2 columns. I am needing to find the totals for each category.

Ex: Dogs = 6, Cats = 2

Please let me know where I went wrong in my formula.

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(--(A2:A9 = "dog")))` or `=COUNTIF(A2:A9, "dog")` or `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(A2:A9 = "dog", 1)))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A9 = "dog"))` and a few others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
={UNIQUE(A2:A9), ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:A9, UNIQUE(A2:A9)))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:A9, "select A,count(A) group by A label count(A)''")
```